# How to change the background color of a row in a react-admin component based on props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm designing a react-admin table, and I want to determine a row's background color by the "active" source of the row - if it's true I want the row background color to be green, otherwise I want it to be red.
I tried material ui's "makeStyles" with no success (all of this stuff is new to me).

This is my table:

```js
const myTable = (props) => {

    return (
        <List {...props} pagination={<PostPagination />}>
            <Datagrid>
                <NumberField source="id" />
                <TextField source="name" />
                <TextField source="category" />
                <TextField source="platform" />
                <NumberField source="major" />
                <NumberField source="minor" />
                <BooleanField source="active" label="active"/>
                <DateField source="audit" />
                <EditButton basePath="versions" />
                <DeleteButton basePath="versions" />
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
    )

}
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: `Datagrid` is custom component ?

Comment: you better show some reproducible example, preffered in codesandbox...

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, i didn't really understand that you have strings here, but there are many different options for example:

1. `<MyRow style={{background: (isActive ? 'red' : 'green')} />`
2. `<MyRow className={isActive ? classes.activeRow : null />`

In the first variant, you do not need to do anything with the styles, and in the second you will have to create a style for example through makeStyles.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    activeRow:{
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
  }));
```